# VS 2019 azure functions missing in publish target

Tags: c#, function, azure, publish

I've recently installed VS2019 Professional.
If I create an Azure function project when I click on "Publish" I see only the option "Folder" as publish target.

I can't see azure functions items as you can see:
[image]

How can I solve?
Thank you.

Comment: Have installed Azure development workloads in Visual Studio 2019? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-4---choose-workloads

Comment: Yes. "Azure development" is installed. Last week with VS2019 Community Edition everything was working fine. Today after VS2019 Professional installation I have this issue.

Comment: did you install azure functions sdk?

Comment: You get it with microsoft.net.sdk.function package. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try?

Updating the [`microsoft.net.sdk.functions`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32340) version to 1.0.29